# Cloudflare and Google search console: Blocked due to access forbidden (403)

Tags: cloudflare, google-search-console, googlebot, google-index

I am using Cloudflare for a website I own, I am facing a problem in google search console when I use URL Inspection/Test live URL I get **URL is not available to Google, Blocked due to access forbidden (403)**, but this error does not show up when I pause **Cloudflare on site** function in Cloudflare dashboard, I have updated robots.txt by adding `Disallow: /cdn-cgi/` as recommended by CF but nothing changed, how to fix this problem, thank you.

Comment: have you find a solution?

Comment: It worked by itself!

Answer (score 4):

Allowing `verified bots` fixed my issue. Here's what you got to do:

1. Go to Security
2. then Bots
3. then Configure Super Bot Fight Mode.

Make sure the `Verified bots` option is set to `Allow`.